# java sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.map is blocked for a minute

Tags: java, block, nio

We have a busy server that uses embedded Jetty and handles around 400 concurrent threads (most of them are jetty threads).

We use the sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.map to map file from file to memory. In most cases it takes 0 - 1 ms to do the map for 2400000 bytes but in some cases (can happen even 4 times in an hour) it takes 58 seconds for this operation.

Before the mapping we exclusively lock the file using the method lock.

Has anyone encountered such situation and may know the cause and the solution?

Thanks Very Much for your time

Comment: "We use the `sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.map` ...". You shouldn't. You should use `java.nio.channels.FileChannel.map().`

Comment: @EJP I assume this is just where the stack trace ends, but you are right, that you should use map() directly for mappings less than 2 GB in size.

Answer (score 1):

I seen this behaviour when a system is over committed for disk usage and/or mappings.  A 2.4 MB mapping is pretty small and I would check you are not creating too many of these at once and you can run out, preventing it from continuing until some old ones are cleaned up.  BTW How are you cleaning them up, are you doing this deterministically, or just discarding them.

I suggest

- don't overload the server with too many active threads.  Less threads can behave better. Consider how many CPUs you actually have.
- don't over commit how much disk you are using at once.  Is your working set larger or smaller than your free memory. Are you using HDD or SSD?  If HDD, you need to ensure you almost never touch the disk, i.e. work entirely from memory/disk cache.
- use larger mappings e.g. 64 MB to 1 GB to reduce the number of mapping. You can use larger mappings but it is unlikely that you need to.
- if you have a large number of concurrent mappings, try to clean up mappings deterministically by calling the Cleaner.clean() to free the mapping.